# Django Image Upload Fails...File not written to directory (weird bug)

Tags: image, apache, upload, django

I have a Django model that is supposed to upload an image to a media directory on my server via an ImageField.

I've done this before successfully on a linux server.  In this case, I've changed the group to www-data and changed permissions to g+w to allow apache to write files to the specific media folder as well as the media root.

When I save the model via both my admin portal and a modelform in the frontend of my site, the model validates. As expected, a link to the file is stored in the database.  But the file isn't written.

This is confusing because A) it is working on my local server and B) I have a different model that successfully saves and writes an image to my server.  I can't figure out why both of those things are working while the other image upload is failing.

Here is my model:

```
    class Post_Photo(models.Model):
       post=models.ForeignKey(Post,blank=True,null=True)
       photo=models.FileField(upload_to="post_photos") 

       def __unicode__(self):
           return str(self.post)
```

Here is my settings file:

```
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/public_html/media'
```

the directory post_photos lives at /home/public_html/media/post_photos.  As I said, I made changes to the group and perms to allow the server to write the files.

Again, when I save a modelform or the model directly through the admin, it gives me the proper link, just no file exists there.

If someone can help me solve this, I will be eternally grateful

Comment: How are you running the Django? mod_wsgi or mod_python?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a variable to define your local storage:

`local_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=SITE_ROOT, base_url='/post_photos')`

Then using that on your model:

`photo = models.FileField(storage=local_storage)`